# How to change image of GridVIew

Tags: android, image, gridview

i am having one GridView that contains some image. I want to change the image by clicking it. I am giving option of choosing image from DialogBox. But problem is that the gridview is not updating the latest image. i found similar question [How can I change Image on Gridview Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201884/how-can-i-change-image-on-gridview-runtime). But even the solution is not working for my case. My code is below.

```
private GridView gridView1,gridView2,gridView3;
private View sepView1,sepView2;
private static WallpaperInfo wall = new WallpaperInfo();

public Integer[] butterflyIds = {
        R.drawable.create_cardz, 
        R.drawable.done_icon,
        R.drawable.email, 
        R.drawable.facebook,
        R.drawable.error_icon, 
        R.drawable.mms_lock,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.icon_plus,
        R.drawable.like, 

};


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("BillingService", "Starting");
    setContentView(R.layout.wallpapersetting);

    gridView1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);
    gridView2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview2);
    gridView3 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview3);

    sepView1 = (View)findViewById(R.id.seperator1);
    sepView2 = (View)findViewById(R.id.seperator2);

    gridView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, butterflyIds));
    final ImageAdapter im = new ImageAdapter(this,butterflyIds);
    //gridView2.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, butterflyIds));
    //gridView3.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,background));


    gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View vi, int position,long id) 
        {
            createDialog(parentView,vi,position,butterflyIds,im,gridView1);

        }

    });


}

 private  void createDialog(final AdapterView<?>  parentView,View v,int pos,Integer[]     ID, final ImageAdapter im, final GridView gv)
{
    final int parentPos= pos;
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    GridView dialogGridView =  (GridView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_grid);
    dialogGridView.setAdapter(new DialogImageAdapter(this,ID));
    dialogGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> dialogParentView, View vi, int position,long id) 
        {
            //parentView.addView(vi, position);
            setImage(dialogParentView.getId(),parentPos,im);
            dialog.dismiss();
            im.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gv.setAdapter(im);
            gv.invalidateViews();

        }

    });
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    dialog.show();  
}

protected void setImage(int viewId,int parentPos, ImageAdapter im) 
{
    im.setFlowerIds(parentPos, viewId);
}
```

My imageAdapter class is this

```
 package com.tdsoc.lw.utils;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
 import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private Integer[] mThumbIds;
private ImageView imageView;
// Keep all Images in array

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c)
{
    mContext = c;
}

public ImageAdapter(Context c, Integer[] mTid)
{
    mContext = c;
    mThumbIds = mTid;
}
@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
     if( convertView == null)
     {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
     }
     else
     {
         imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
     }
     imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
     //notifyDataSetChanged();
     return imageView;
}
public Integer[] getFlowerIds()
{
    return mThumbIds;
}
public  void setFlowerIds(int pos,int ID )
{
    mThumbIds[pos]= ID;
}

 }
```

Comment: why are you creating two instances of your adapter in your onCreate method? Why not just create one instance and set that instance to the gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter method `setFlowerIds` add the method `notifyDataSetChanged();` this might fix your issue.

```
public  void setFlowerIds(int pos,int ID )
{
    mThumbIds[pos]= ID;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // add this method
}
```

**EDIT** : this is how I refresh my `BaseAdapter` see if this works for you. Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491876/how-to-use-adapter-notifydatasetchanged-where-i-have-to-use-these-line-for-my/15492143?noredirect=1#comment21940270_15492143) question

```
public synchronized void refresAdapter(List<Item> newItems) {
    _items.clear(); //my adapter list
    _items.addAll(newItems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: "_items" would be the same as your "mThumbIds" array in your adapter (i'm just using an ArrayList) and "newItems" will be the new List passed from my activity with the new data to update my adapter with.

Comment: You might get an error that will tell you to run the refresh on your UI thread. If that happens just check out my answer in the link that I added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new `GridView` everytime someone clicks on an item..?

Either way, you want to ensure you're calling `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` on the adapter to force it to redraw all the views.

Comment: the second gridview is for displaying the images in dialogBox. The problem is that the clicked image is becoming invisible when i am selecting to update from dialog's image