# Change GridView images on item click at run time in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

i am using GridView in application. and i wants that when i click on item it should replace on another array picture. actually i used two array when application run first time, the GridView  will show the first array picture , after that when i  click  on item it should replace by the  second array picture according to its position.
i did try but did't solve. so any one help me..

GridViewContent.java

```
public class GridViewContent extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public int pictureArray[]={
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,        
    };
    public GridViewContent(Context c){
        context=c;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (pictureArray.length);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pictureArray[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView myimage=new ImageView(context);
        myimage.setImageResource(pictureArray[position]);
        myimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        myimage.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));


        return myimage;
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Context ctx;
    GridViewContent grid1 = new GridViewContent(ctx);
    // GridView grid;
    /*
     * static final int[] numbers = new int[] {
     * R.drawable.question,R.drawable.question
     * ,R.drawable.question,R.drawable.question
     * ,R.drawable.question,R.drawable.question, R.drawable.question,
     * 
     * };
     */
    public int OriginalArray[] = { R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4,
            R.drawable.sample_5, R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7, };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_memory);
        grid.setAdapter(new GridViewContent(this));
        // grid.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
        grid.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id = v.getId();
                ImageView pictImage = new ImageView(ctx);
                int imgView = OriginalArray[id];
                pictImage.setImageResource(imgView);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gv_memory"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

</GridView>
```

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some little changes as below:

```
public class GridViewContent extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public int pictureArray[]={
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,
            R.drawable.question,        
    };

 public int OriginalArray[] = { R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4,
            R.drawable.sample_5, R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7, };

    public GridViewContent(Context c){
        context=c;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (pictureArray.length);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pictureArray[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView myimage=new ImageView(context);
        myimage.setImageResource(pictureArray[position]);
        myimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        myimage.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));




       myimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myimage.setImageResources(Original[arg2]);
        }
    });
        return myimage;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sir this line gives an error, **myimage.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){

       myimage.setImageResource(OriginalArray[position]);**

Answer (score 0):

Implement onitemclicklistener for gridview.Refer this site   http://[www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/).   write your changing logic inside this and call adapter.notifydatasetChanged(). http://[stackoverflow.com/questions/6201884/how-can-i-change-image-on-gridview-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201884/how-can-i-change-image-on-gridview-runtime)

Comment: please Sir help me how i do this?